# Do we need to delete the image variable to recycle memory space

Tags: memory-leaks, dm-script

all:
If we use GMS's Python script, we need to manually delete the global image variable. Otherwise, it will always be in the memory. For DM script, do we need to do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The only thing that lingers in memory are object variables declared on the main-script (i.e. not within `{}`)
The latter can lead to an image being kept in memory, if the object holds an image.

You can test this with the following example script:

```c
Class CMemoryHog
{
    image img
    CMemoryHog(object self){ Result("\n Script object created:\t"+self.ScriptObjectGetID()); img:=realImage("Test",4,100,100);}
    ~CMemoryHog(object self){ Result("\n Script object destroyed:\t"+self.ScriptObjectGetID()); }
}

ClearResults()
Result("\n# Test1: Images in memory:"+CountImages())
Alloc(CMemoryHog)
Result("\n# Test1: Images in memory:"+CountImages())

{
    Result("\n\n\n# Test2: Images in memory:"+CountImages())
    Object ob1 = Alloc(CMemoryHog)
    Result("\n# Test2: Images in memory:"+CountImages())
}

Result("\n\n\n# Test3: Images in memory:"+CountImages())
Object ob2 = Alloc(CMemoryHog)
Result("\n# Test3: Images in memory:"+CountImages())
```

Test1 allocates the object, but immediately destroys it afterwards.

Test2 allocates the object and references it by a local variable, but that variable gets removed once the local scope is left.

Test3 allocates the object and references it by a "global" variable. Global object variables stay in scope when the script ends.

---

The following script can be useful to "watch out" for images that are kept in scope (even if they are not displayed):

```c
Class CMemLeakWatch : UIFrame{
    CMemLeakWatch(object self) {Result("\n Created object '"+self.ScriptObjectGetClassName()+"' #"+self.ScriptObjectGetID());}
    ~CMemLeakWatch(object self) {Result("\n Destroyed object '"+self.ScriptObjectGetClassName()+"' #"+self.ScriptObjectGetID());}
    number taskID
    object Launch(object self, number refreshrate_sec){
        string name = "Memory Leak Watch"
        TagGroup DLGtgs, DLGItems
        DLGtgs = DLGCreateDialog( name, DLGItems )
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateTextBox(40,10,0).DLGIdentifier("ListField") )  
        self.Init(DLGtgs)
        self.Display(name)        
        taskID = self.AddMainThreadPeriodicTask("UpdateMem",refreshrate_sec)
        return self        
    }
    void AboutToCloseDocument(object self){ RemoveMainThreadTask(taskID);}
    void UpdateMem(object self){
        string listStr
        for( number i=0; i<CountImages(); i++){
            image img := FindImageByIndex(i)
            if (img.ImageIsValid()) 
                listStr += "[" + img.ImageGetLabel()+"]:"+img.ImageGetName()+"\n"
        }
        self.SetTextElementData("ListField",listStr)
    }
}

Alloc(CMemLeakWatch).Launch(0.2)
``
```

Comment: DM scripting uses a memory management scheme called "reference counting." Every time an object is assigned to a variable, the object's reference count is increased by one. Every time a variable that refers to an object goes out of scope, the object's reference count is decreased by one. Once the reference count on an object reaches zero, it's destructor is called and it is deallocated. As noted by BmyGuest, global variables in scripts never go out of scope (not sure why), so the reference counts of the objects to which they refer never go down to zero.

Comment: Another way to make a variable "let go" of an object to which it is assigned is to nullify it, i.e. set it equal to null, as in objectVariable = null.

Comment: @MikeKundmann Global object *not* going out of scope are useful if one wants to keep some otherwise not referenced code in scope, so that it can be accessed. (One can access objects by their ID) I think, however, it is mainly a 'historic' feature.
Also: Not all global variables are kept, just objects. TagGroup or images, f.e., do not linger.